# Browser not converting &amp; (&) when passed through URI

Tags: php, xml, rss, uri, ampersand

I have an RSS 2.0 Item element which requires a link for the RSS to validate. I want to insert a URI within the link element to link to a page on my website. Within this URI I used `&amp;` instead of `&` to separate the different parameters I pass through the URI. When I do this the RSS is able to be validated, however when I copy and paste the URI within the link element into the browser, the browser does not convert it into an `&` to denote the separation of the URI parameters.

The XML encoding I use is UTF-8.

The URI which I use is:

```
http://www.stacks.co.uk/rapmusic/albums.php?echonest_id=ARD5VN51187B9B8D29&amp;deezer_id=3505&amp;artist_name=Jamie+Foxx&amp;artist_image=http%3A%2F%2Fuserserve-ak.last.fm%2Fserve%2F_%2F95148.jpg
```

I also tried to use `%26` instead of `&amp;` but even that did not allow me to go to my URI.

Comment: how do you encode special characters, and how do you decode them? String wuery needs to be seperated with `&` but if you want to pass `7` as a GET  data you need to encode it into `%26`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to break the RSS XML, you will always need to use `&amp;` rather than `&` in URLs with parameters. When the RSS is rendered for feeds, it will automatically convert the ASCII symbol to a usable URL equivalent; i.e. this:

```
http://example.com/script.php?param1=foo&amp;param2=bar
```

Will become:

```
http://example.com/script.php?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

If you look at the actual XML, however, it will still show the decoded values - so don't let it fool you. I had the same issue a month or so ago.

Comment: OMG thank you. All this time for two hours I was copy and pasting the URI from veiw source instead of actually copy and pasting the HTML page URI. I was so fixated into thinking that the user will use view source to find the URI that is placed in the link element that I forgot that they would in fact look at the actual HTML page.

Comment: I think I spent a good hour scratching my head too! Got to the stage where I was thinking about rewriting my PHP framework to wrap the URL in `CDATA` :P